# Angular material input to localeString isn't binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular11

I'm using angular material 11.2 and have a requirement where I'm trying to convert the entered string to US dollars.

I have tried the following,

```
<input matInput formControlName="test" (onkeyup)="onKeyUpTest($event)" type="text">

onKeyUpTest(event){
var localNum = event.target.value.toLocaleString('en-US');
this.formGroup.patchValue({
'test': localNum
)}
}
```

This is binding the value but without commas.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Intl.numberFormat function.

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-us', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(number));
```

Output: `"$123,456.79"`

References: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Comment: this is converting the value to USD but, this is now not binding back the value to HTML on change

Comment: Can you create a stackBlitz link of the code?